# Use string variable as Applescript command argument

Tags: escaping, applescript, quotes

I'm trying to do the following:

```
on cleanup(x)
   tell application "Finder"    
      clean up window 1 by x
   end tell
end cleanup

cleanup("name")
```

However since x variable is a string, the clean up command doesn't accept it and exits with error. Is there a way to convert the string to something that the commands accepts or some other solution to unquote the variable without using if, else statements like this:

```
on cleanup(x)
   tell application "Finder"
      if x is "name" then
          clean up window 1 by name
      end if
   end tell
end cleanup

cleanup("name")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work.

```
    on cleanup(x)

    run script "tell application \"Finder\" to  clean up window 1 by " & space & x



end cleanup

cleanup("name")
```

---

From the **StandardAdditions** Library

run script v : Run a specified script or script file

- run script script : the script text (or an alias or file reference to
  a script file) to run

  - [with parameters list of any] : a list of parameters
  - [in text] : the scripting component to use; default is the current scripting component

→ any : the result of running the script