# How to convert a variable hidden in a string in applescript to a readable variable?

Tags: variables, applescript, undefined

I made a mail macro in applescript to send mails to different people using excel as data (eg Dear <name>, Your team mates are <teammate1> and <teammate2>). This script works.

To make the script more flexible and also usable for other people I put the mail message in a text-file, using the pseudo-code from above.

themessage.txt

```
Dear <firstname>, Your team mates are <teammate1> and <teammate2>.
```

I let the script then change the text from themessage.txt to applescript syntax:

```
“Dear “ & firstname & “, Your team mates are “ & teammate1 & “ and “ & teammate2 & “.”
```

And saved it in a variable:

```
set themessage to “Dear “ & firstname & “, Your team mates are “ & teammate1 & “ and “ & teammate2 & “.”
```

Unfortunately this was interpreted as a long string without variables.

That is why I used ‘run script’ (see: [Use string variable as Applescript command argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15752249/use-string-variable-as-applescript-command-argument)). But now the variables (<firstname>, <teammate1> and <teammate2>) are not defined. It gives script error 2753: the variable firstname is not defined.

Using

```
property name: “”
```

or

```
global name
set name to “”
```

does not solve the problem.

I have isolated the problem I have in the following code:

```
set firstname to "Alice" as text

--Read contents of themessage.txt. and save it to variable themessage
tell application "Finder"
    set current_path to container of (path to me) as text
end tell

set txtfile to (current_path & "themessage.txt") as alias
open for access txtfile
set themessage to (read txtfile)
close access txtfile

--Convert text string to command
run script "set thecontent to" & space & themessage
```

and the simplified themessage.txt

```
"Dear " & firstname & ","
```

What should I change in order for the variable firstname to be recognized in the line with ‘run script’?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can place your statement(s) into a `run` handler that accepts a list of arguments, and use the `with parameters` parameter of the `run script` command to pass the arguments to the script.  Multiple arguments can be placed in the list, where they are used like regular handler positional parameters, for example:

```
set someVariable to "Alice"

set textFile to "path:to:message.txt" as alias -- the path to the text file
set theMessage to (read textFile) -- no need to use access for just reading

set theScript to "
on run {firstname} -- the variable names used in the script
   return " & theMessage & "
end run"

-- Run the script and get the result
set theResult to (run script theScript with parameters {someVariable}) -- the variables to pass to the script
```

See the [AppleScript Language Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW36) for more information.